# EasySlider. How to replace images by content of a web page?

Tags: viewer, easyslider

EasySlide is a very good viewer, but I want to produce a rotation of web pages and not images. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I suppose so.

```
<div id="slider"> 
  <ul>              
      <li>
           <iframe src="whatyouwanthere.html" .../> 
      </li>
 . 
 .
 .
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Don't forget to set the height and width and border=0 for the iframes though. Else the whole thing is gonna turn out real ugly.